# How to avoid <input /> field from showing `next` option instead of `go` (On mobile keyboard)

Tags: android, html-input

Having an input field like:

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Will automatically (on Android) change the `Enter` option on you keyboard to `Next`, and it will jump to the next field.

How to avoid this *behaviour*?

In my case I'm using an input field to add tags to (or `Chips`), which works fine on its own on mobile because the appropriate event is fired.

But when the `Next` button shows, it seems to simulate pressing `tab` on your keyboard, i.e. it goes to the next field. I need it to behave as `submit` instead.

(Also can't find any relevant specs on this keyboard displaying behaviour, it seems to be a free-formed android specific thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution or workaround is to set the type to `search`:

```html
<input type="search" />
```

It's a bit odd to have to press a magnifying glass to add a tag in my usecase, but it works. And any of the other property values don't seem to produce the same result as I want: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Like `submit` will trigger submitting the form, not the field, afaik.

Answer (score 16):

The correct way to fix this is to use the [enterkeyhint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/enterkeyhint) attribute, for instance:

```html
<input type="text" enterkeyhint="done"/>
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer for it is the correct and well normed way to do it.

Comment: This does not work with the `type="search"` which changes the *behaviour* of the enter key, whereas the `enterkeyhint` does *not*

Comment: @TrySpace What do you mean? I just tried again and `<input type="text" enterkeyhint="done" />
<input type="text"/>` does prevent the enter key to move to the next field.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the input type to `search` works fine but I found another alternative to solve it keeping original input type. Just adding the attribute `tabindex="-1"` in all form inputs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31981342)